# Transposing columns 2 by 2 in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where i want to tranpose the column after the nth column. The transpose should be by 2 column.

For eg
Row 1 should be ID ,n+1th column name, n+2th column name , n+1th column value, n+2th column value

Row 2 should be ID ,n+3th column name, n+4th column name , n+3th column value, n+4th column value

Sample Data :

My Import Table is like this :

| Player ID | Team 1 | Team 2 | Team 3 | Team 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player_1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Player_2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

Team 1 v/s Team 2
Team 3 v/s Team 4

My output would be like

| Player ID | Teams 1 | Teams 2 | Score 1 | Score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player_1 | Team 1 | Team 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Player_1 | Team 3 | Team 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Player_2 | Team 1 | Team 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Player_2 | Team 3 | Team 4 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added a sample

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry about that i am using Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: @TashilMoorateeah . . . You have a real problem if you don't know what columns are in your tables.  This data should already be stored in the format you want to convert it to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. The table is deleted and created on the file by the requirement of the system am building

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a union approach here:

```sql
SELECT PlayerID, 'Team 1' AS "Teams 1", 'Team 2' AS "Teams 2",
       Team1 AS "Score 1", Team2 AS "Score 2" FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT PlayerID, 'Team 3', 'Team 4', Team3, Team4 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY PlayerID, "Teams 1";
```

Comment: Actually the number of teams following is unknown. So i have a 2n number of teams

Comment: @TashilMoorateeah, mention your problem clearly. Otherwise, time is getting wasted for others to rework on the problem.

Comment: @TashilMoorateeah If the number of teams really be unknown, then you might need dynamic SQL to generate the query you want.

Comment: @VenkataramanR I did explain this at the start of the thread , i just provided a sample below. I will try to be more clear. thanks

Comment: @TashilMoorateeah, sorry. I saw sample input and output and got confused. I understand the problem better now.